# What can cause a browser not to execute a script?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, google-chrome, browser

For some reason, my browser (both Firefox and Chromium) won't execute the scripts on this page: savageworkouts.com. Yet there are no errors reported in the console whatsoever. Any idea why?

EDIT: Some nice answers below pointed out that some scripts weren't firing due to having `src=""` attributes.

EDIT: I discovered that scripts are being executed but it chokes when it gets to modernizr.foundation.js at the bottom of the page. Any idea why modernizr.foundation.js can't be executed yet there are no errors being reported inside Inspector's console?

EDIT: Solved: I was missing the closing tag for a div on the page (#contentContainer). What's interesting is that missing the closing tag caused Chromium and Firefox both not to be able to continue past executing modernizr.foundation.js.

Comment: are the scripts loaded? are the urls correct? are you using the latest (non-cached) version of the page? and ***is JS turned on?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script src="">
            alert('whyTheF Won\' this fire?');
</script>

.....
<script src="">
                var isIE = false,
                    isChrome = false;
                                    isChrome = true;
                            </script>
```

Why the F won't it fire? I'll tell you why. You've added an `src` attribute. Now the browser is trying to load a nonexistant script from an <s>undefined</s> URL that refers to the current page. `<script src="url.js">doStuff()</script>` will always load `url.js` and execute it, but will *not* execute `doStuff()`.

Comment: Hmm Interesting. I didn't know that. As a matter of fact, before recent updates, those scripts were working even with src="". But yeah, I removed them, and they fire... But the weird thing is that none of the other scripts seem to fire (the ones with valid src attributes). Or, well, at least the browser isn't spitting out any errors, which is the wierd part.

Comment: The URI isn't undefined. It is a relative URI that resolves to the URI of the HTML document being viewed.

Comment: @trusktr: if you're talking about less.js, it _is_ firing.

Comment: Oh yeah, it is.... hmmm.... Well the scripts aren't being executed all the way through, although there are no errors being shown in the Inspector console... Hmmm...

Comment: So I discovered that the browsers are choking when they get to modernizr.foundation.js at the bottom of the page. Any idea why? The strange thing is that it was working before I removed some HTML elements. And even stranger is that there are no errors being reported.

Comment: @trusktr: modernizr.js is loading for me (the `Modernizr` object exists in the chrome dev console). What is the expected functionality?

Comment: Wow, well I found the problem. I was missing the closing div tag for #contentContainer. I added it then everything started working. The expected result is that the drop down menus will work and the face in the side bar will look at your mouse. For some reason, missing the closing `</div>` tag for #contentContainer makes my Chromium and Firefox not get past modernizr.foundation.js. It seems modernizr goes on an endless loop of some sort.

Comment: @trusktr: Yeah, bad HTML/XML does that.

Answer (score 7):

```
<script src="">
            alert('whyTheF Won\' this fire?');
</script>
```

Because the script has a `src`. It tries to load the HTML document as a script, fails, then doesn't execute the inline script because it supports external scripts and the element "has" an external script.

Comment: Hmm, interesting observation. I removed the src="" attribute, and the alert() fires, but no other scripts on the page fire!

Comment: @trusktr — They also have `src=""` you have to remove those too.